# Need to update files to SVN

Tags: svn

I never used any svn tools,so I need help. I worked on some project,and changed some pages,not the whole wesite. Should I put only that files to svn or need to put entire web site? Please answer asap. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have followed the regular workflow of

- checkout the entire website.
- made changes to a few files

All you need is a

```
svn commit -m "Your commit message"
```

This will update the repository to a new revision, updating only the files you have changed.

Comment: Sorry if I ask stupid things,but is this command for Linux? I use windows.

Comment: @MrCkobe If you have installed svn, this should work on windows too.

Comment: is it enough to install TortoiseSVN? I need to update files on company's svn.

Comment: I guess, so. But remember you need to 1: checkout 2: update 3: commit. The folder you are working in keeps track of your changes.

Comment: Last time I checked, TortoiseSVN does not install the standard SVN command line tools.  Try SlikSVN (http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download)